# Azure ARM VM creation with Network Security Groups

Tags: firewall, azure, squid, http-proxy

I have a network with enabled Network Security Groups where I deny Outbound Port 80 and 443. All Outbound traffic is managed through a Squid Proxy.

Now, I want to create a new Virtual Machine in this Network using the Azure ARM templates using the resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines. The problem is that after creation of the Azure Storage Account the VM can't connect to it as the Outbound Port 80 and 443 are denied.

Is it possible to give the resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines some proxy settings?

Comment: Hi, why not change the Network Security group and add a rule that allows the new virtual machine access to the ports? as long as the new rule has a lower priority number it will be processed before the rule that blocks all the other VMs from accessing port 80 and 443.

Comment: Yes that would be possible, but actually I don't want to do this, as I have a ARM template creating more than just one virtual machine. I don't want to allow http and https access from all those machines and after creating them successfully deny it again. I think this is not a very good solution.

Comment: To be clear then, you an ARM template that will deploy multiple VMs, one of the VMs needs to be able to access Outboud Port 80 and Port 443 but not the others? the NSG is already linked to an existing Network, and it is on to this network that the VMs will be deployed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have an issue with your design. If your network security group protecting your traffic to the Internet then your traffic to your azure storage should work just fine for your hard disks in Azure storage. That connection doesn't run over the internet. Take another look at your design.

Comment: @Brian Lewis: Yes that is true, but I have found out that the problem is when using VM extensions where it needs Outbound Internet connection to download them.